# A function written in useEffect printing a value twice when the if condition got true. Can anyone help me to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

- I want to create a reminder feature of the task. Basically the idea is that in my note app while any user creating their task, at that time i ask a reminder date-time from it and then store it into DB and when that date-time comes then i will push a email of that particular note.
- To achieve this, my logic is i convert the DB reminder date-time in seconds and i get the current date-time and also convert it into seconds. After that i do operation - **let msgTime = remind - currentDateSec**. where **currentDateSec** is current date-time and **remind** is the DB date-time. and then store it in msgTime variable.
- When **msgTime == 0** then i will push the reminder mail to user register mail id. But here i wrote Hi for the the testing purpose and this Hi is printing 2 times in the console, and i don't want it. I want to print it only one time only.
- To check every second i called my function in setinterval and run it after 1000ms.

  ```
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    function checkReminder() {
      let remind = 0;
      let currentDate = new Date();
      let currentDateSec = Math.floor(currentDate.getTime() / 1000);

      for (let index = 0; index < notes.length; index++) {
        remind = notes[index].reminderTime;
        let msgTime = remind - currentDateSec;
        console.log(msgTime);

        if (msgTime === 0) {
          console.log("hi");
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }
    }
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      checkReminder();
    }, 1000);
  })
  ```
- This code is for fetching the notes from database.

> ```
> const fetchNotes = async () => {
>     try {
>       let res = await axios.get("/api/notes", config);
>       setNotes(res.data);
>       // console.log(notes); 
>     } catch (err) {
>       setError(err.response.res);
>     }
>   };
> ```

- See the terminal output here -
  [Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlXuc.jpg)

**Note : I already removed React.StrictMode**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this return statement to your `useEffect` function and you will be fine:

```
useEffect(() => {
        function checkReminder() {
            let remind = 0;
            let currentDate = new Date();
            let currentDateSec = Math.floor(currentDate.getTime() / 1000);

            for (let index = 0; index < notes.length; index++) {
                remind = notes[index].reminderTime;
                let msgTime = remind - currentDateSec;
                console.log(msgTime);

                if (msgTime === 0) {
                    console.log("hi");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }
        }
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            checkReminder();
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    })
```

It's sometimes necessary to return the cleanup function from `useEffect` to avoid further triggers.

Comment: Hey @MohammadSalehi  thanx its work for me But can you tell me the reason why this is happening.

Comment: it's all about cleanup, you can read the official react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) about it. to give you an overview, when you return a function from `useEffect`, it is called when that component unmounts so it's important to clear the interval when the component unmounts so it no longer triggers. also this [link](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks) might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MohammadSalehi, this is something new for me..